# Scroll options_ui into view, Firefox webextension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm updating my extension with an options_ui and when the user updates the extension I call `browser.runtime.openOptionspage()` to make them aware of the new options page, but for some screen sizes the options_ui is not visible so for a better user experience I want to scroll my form with radio buttons into view, I've tried .scrollIntoView() on an input element but it does not appear to work.
I have a feeling this might not be possible in the context of about:addons is this possible?

Here's an image of what I mean, https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7uBw.png

my options page/code:

```
<body>
  <form>
      <label>Enable for:</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="setting" id="global" value="global"> All tabs<br>
      <input type="radio" name="setting" id="tabs" value="tabs"> Only tabs I click the icon in
  </form>
  <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
```

```
function restoreOptions() {
  document.getElementById("tabs").scrollIntoView(); //nada
  var mode_getter = browser.storage.local.get("tab_mode");
  mode_getter.then((obj) => {
    switch (obj.tab_mode) {
      case "tabs":
        document.getElementById("tabs").checked = true;
        break;
      default:
        document.getElementById("global").checked = true;
    }
  });

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restoreOptions);
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("change", saveOptions);
```

Comment: The options are inside a container so you can't scroll the parent page. Looks like Firefox developers haven't thought about smaller popular display sizes. I'd say it's a design bug and should be reported on their bugzilla.

Comment: There's no actual official solution. As suggested, file a bug. However, you can always open your options page in a separate tab or window with just your options. The options page is just another HTML page, which can be opened anywhere.

Comment: I ended up using a smaller about:addons description which brings the form elements higher up the page.
I was aware of the separate options page but If I go down that route then the options are not available in about:addons?  
I personally like the look of the addons page vs a completely separate options page.